# How can I revert a single file to a version I committed in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, revert

I have my `index.cshtml` file and I made a ton of changes to it. However, I want to scrap it and return to the a working (commited) version of this **single file**.

How can I use Mercurial to accomplish this?

I'm using Visual Studio 2011 with VisualHG.

Answer (score 3):

The command is called `hg revert`, you should be able to find something like that in VisualHg.

It looks like you already know what the command is named (since you used it as a tag). Is it not available in VisualHg? I would guess it's available in the context menu (i.e. right click) for the file.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on the file you want to revert and select "Revert Changes", this will show the revert window where you can see the file diff and perform the reversion by clicking the "Revert" button in the botom right corner.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times, when you make a lot of modifications to a file, you may find out that some of them are useful ( I do, at least ). Of course, for reverting the whole contents of the file, you should use `revert` as others have suggested. If however, you think you may have something useful in your current modifications, that you'd like to keep, consider using the [record](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RecordExtension) extension. It's an extension that ships with Mercurial, and it will allow you to choose whether or not you want to include some (c)hunks in your next commit.